# Vba Excel LinkedCell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to solve a problem. I want to change in vba code `.LinkedCell = "main!$AD$3"` to variable
For example:

```
.LinkedCell = Arkusz1.Cells(Rownum, Column)
```

It's compile but it doesn't work

Comment: is your `Arkusz1` name `main`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this- a kind of string reference to your sheet and range:

```
.LinkedCell = Arkusz1.Name & "!" & Arkusz1.Cells(Rownum, Column).Address
```

Comment: I get "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: and answer my comment under your question!!

Comment: I can't add comment under my question, maybe some kind of bug